# Is it possible to import a third party's symmetric key into SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, encryption-symmetric

A third-party sends us a large CSV, an export from their (non-SQL Server) database. Several encrypted columns from their database were exported to CSV without being decrypted first.  Separately, they sent us the symmetric key which they used to encrypt those columns of data.

We can decrypt those columns of data using a .NET program and the AesManaged classes before we import it into SQL Server; but is it possible to skip that step and decrypt those columns of data *using T-SQL* with  their symmetric key after the data has been imported?  Are there any decryption utilities in SQL Server that accept an AES_256 key as a parameter?

Comment: I can suggest you to take look at [Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-ver15) about encrypting/decrypting data using t-sql

Comment: [Managing SQL Server and Database Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-and-database-encryption-keys-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#managing-sql-server-and-database-keys) mentions: "Restore a previously saved key to a database. This enables a new server instance to access existing data that it did not originally encrypt." It does not mention _how_.

Comment: This answer suggests that it's not possible: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65570/29446